# Using .each function to take a value, then edit and put the result in other objet propery

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm trying to make a script that take the URL of the "img src" then edit and finally put it on "a data-title= href", all them on each "item-foo item-bar item-foo bar"
The edition works and I get the link but then I can't make the change
I Try to do an "each" inside another "each" but it doesn't work, next try to return with the variable "video" but only the last one comes out.

I hope to explain myself well, English unfortunately is not my native language and on top of that I am learning javascript by kicks haha. My regards and respects.

I hope to explain myself well, English unfortunately is not my native language and on top of that I am learning javascript by kicks haha. My regards and respects!

```
<div class="item-foo item-bar item-foo bar">

  <div class="inner-block">

    <a data-title="" href="https://example.com/news/16143-chair.htm" title="Chair with rotten legs">
      <span class="image">
<img src="https://thumbs.example.com/thumbs/v/i/d/e/o/chair38630.mp4/chair38630.mp4-3.jpg" alt="Chair with rotten legs" />
            </span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item-foo item-bar item-foo bar">
    //similar content, diferent URLs
  </div>

  <script>
    jQuery("span.image img").each(function() {

      direccion = $(this).prop("src");
      edit1 = direccion.replace("thumbs", "media");
      edit2 = edit1.replace("thumbs", "videos");
      index = edit2.indexOf("mp4");
      video = edit2.slice(0, index + 3);

      //console.log("The URL of the video is: " + video);

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the containing `<a>` you can use `.closest('a')` and then set the `.attr()`

```js
jQuery("span.image img").each(function() {
  direccion = $(this).prop("src").replace("thumbs", "media").replace("thumbs", "videos");
  $(this).closest('a').attr('href',direccion.slice(0, direccion.indexOf("mp4") + 3));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-foo item-bar item-foo bar">

  <div class="inner-block">

    <a data-title="" href="https://example.com/news/16143-chair.htm" title="Chair with rotten legs"> Right click and check href
      <span class="image">
<img src="https://thumbs.example.com/thumbs/v/i/d/e/o/chair38630.mp4/chair38630.mp4-3.jpg" alt="Chair with rotten legs" />
            </span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item-foo item-bar item-foo bar">
    <!--similar content, diferent URLs-->
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks Kinglish, not to the image but to each `a data-title="" href=`, I try with `$("div.inner-block a").attr('href',direccion.slice(0, direccion.indexOf("mp4") + 3));` but not work to each.

Comment: @VictorVincenzo - I see. Check my updated answer and see if that helps.

Comment: impeccable!! I'm not lying if I tell you that I spent a week looking for a solution without success and studying through the "jquery". But instead of studying everything from cero I wanted to take a shortcut to do something a little more fun. Now is the time to continue studying. Thank you very much!!